# Breaking a string apart into a sequence of words

Tags: algorithm, search, search-engine, complexity-theory

I recently came across the following interview question:

> Given an input string and a dictionary of words, implement a method that breaks up the input string into a space-separated string of dictionary words that a search engine might use for "Did you mean?" For example, an input of "applepie" should yield an output of "apple pie".

I can't seem to get an optimal solution as far as complexity is concerned.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the question is exactly my interview problem, down to the example I used in the [post](http://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/) at The Noisy Channel. Glad you liked the solution. Am quite sure you can't beat the O(n^2) dynamic programming / memoization solution I describe for worst-case performance.

You can do better in practice if your dictionary and input aren't pathological. For example, if you can identify in linear time the substrings of the input string are in the dictionary (e.g., with a trie) and if the number of such substrings is constant, then the overall time will be linear. Of course, that's a lot of assumptions, but real data is often much nicer than a pathological worst case.

There are also fun variations of the problem to make it harder, such as enumerating all valid segmentations, outputting a best segmentation based on some definition of best, handling a dictionary too large to fit in memory, and handling inexact segmentations (e.g., correcting spelling mistakes). Feel free to comment on my blog or otherwise contact me to follow up.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I had a question after reading your great blog post. The O(2^n) still puzzles me for the general solution although intuitively it might make sense. I tried using a conbinatorics to solve it as well as solving the recurrence (T(n) = n*T(n-1) + O(k)) but I can only get a bound involving the product of n! with the Gamma function. Did you try solving the recurrence as well to come up with the O(2^n)?

Answer (score 8):

This **[link](http://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/)** describes this problem as a perfect interview question and provides several methods to solve it.  Essentially it involves [**recursive backtracking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).  At this level it would produce an O(2^n) complexity.  An efficient solution using memoization could bring this problem down to O(n^2).

Comment: thanks a ton, to help me get this beauty link!!.. wat can be a perfect answer..hail this man who gave such a respect to a problem, i was asked the same in google interview once!!

Comment: We have an outer loop running over length of string (say i=1:length(s) where s is the input string) and an inner loop running upto current prefix index i (say j=1:i). Since we expect each suffix to be looked up in the dictionary only the first time (rest of lookups will be in the map), the running time is O(n^2). Is this reasoning correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Using python, we can write two function, the first one `segment` returns the first segmentation of a piece of contiguous text into words given a dictionary or `None` if no such segmentation is found. Another function `segment_all` returns a list of all segmentations found. Worst case complexity is O(n**2) where n is the input string length in chars.

The solution presented here can be extended to include spelling corrections and bigram analysis to determine the most likely segmentation.

```
def memo(func):
    '''
    Applies simple memoization to a function
    '''
    cache = {}
    def closure(*args):
        if args in cache:
            v = cache[args]
        else:
            v = func(*args)
            cache[args] = v
        return v
    return closure


def segment(text, words):
    '''
    Return the first match that is the segmentation of 'text' into words
    '''
    @memo
    def _segment(text):
        if text in words: return text
        for i in xrange(1, len(text)):
            prefix, suffix = text[:i], text[i:]
            segmented_suffix = _segment(suffix)
            if prefix in words and segmented_suffix:
                return '%s %s' % (prefix, segmented_suffix)
        return None
    return _segment(text)


def segment_all(text, words):
    '''
    Return a full list of matches that are the segmentation of 'text' into words
    '''
    @memo
    def _segment(text):
        matches = []
        if text in words: 
            matches.append(text)
        for i in xrange(1, len(text)):
            prefix, suffix = text[:i], text[i:]
            segmented_suffix_matches = _segment(suffix)
            if prefix in words and len(segmented_suffix_matches):
                for match in segmented_suffix_matches:
                    matches.append('%s %s' % (prefix, match))
        return matches 
    return _segment(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    string = 'cargocultscience'
    words = set('car cargo go cult science'.split())
    print segment(string, words)
    # >>> car go cult science
    print segment_all(string, words)
    # >>> ['car go cult science', 'cargo cult science']
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store all valid English words in a trie.  Once you've done this, you could start walking the trie from the root downward, following the letters in the string.  Whenever you find a node that's marked as a word, you have two options:

1. Break the input at this point, or
2. Continue extending the word.

You can claim that you've found a match once you have broken the input up into a set of words that are all legal and have no remaining characters left.  Since at each letter you either have one forced option (either you are building a word that isn't valid and should stop -or- you can keep extending the word) or two options (split or keep going), you could implement this function using exhaustive recursion:

```
PartitionWords(lettersLeft, wordSoFar, wordBreaks, trieNode):
    // If you walked off the trie, this path fails.
    if trieNode is null, return.

    // If this trie node is a word, consider what happens if you split
    // the word here.
    if trieNode.isWord:
        // If there is no input left, you're done and have a partition.
        if lettersLeft is empty, output wordBreaks + wordSoFar and return

        // Otherwise, try splitting here.
        PartitinWords(lettersLeft, "", wordBreaks + wordSoFar, trie root)

    // Otherwise, consume the next letter and continue:
    PartitionWords(lettersLeft.substring(1), wordSoFar + lettersLeft[0], 
                   wordBreaks, trieNode.child[lettersLeft[0])
```

In the pathologically worst case this will list all partitions of the string, which can t exponentially long.  However, this only occurs if you can partition the string in a huge number of ways that all start with valid English words, and is unlikely to occur in practice. If the string has many partitions, we might spend a lot of time finding them, though.  For example, consider the string "dotheredo." We can split this many ways:

```
do the redo
do the red o
doth ere do
dot here do
dot he red o
dot he redo
```

To avoid this, you might want to institute a limit of the number of answers you report, perhaps two or three.

Since we cut off the recursion when we walk off the trie, if we ever try a split that doesn't leave the remainder of the string valid, we will detect this pretty quickly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> import java.util.*;

```
class Position {
    int indexTest,no;
    Position(int indexTest,int no)
    {
        this.indexTest=indexTest;
        this.no=no;
    } } class RandomWordCombo {
    static boolean isCombo(String[] dict,String test)
    {
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dic=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        Stack<Position> pos=new Stack<Position>();
        for(String each:dict)
        {
            if(dic.containsKey(""+each.charAt(0)))
            {
                //System.out.println("=========it is here");
                ArrayList<String> temp=dic.get(""+each.charAt(0));
                temp.add(each);
                dic.put(""+each.charAt(0),temp);
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
                temp.add(each);
                dic.put(""+each.charAt(0),temp);
            }
        }
        Iterator it = dic.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println("key: "+pair.getKey());
        for(String str:(ArrayList<String>)pair.getValue())
        {
            System.out.print(str);
        }
    }
        pos.push(new Position(0,0));
        while(!pos.isEmpty())
        {
            Position position=pos.pop();
            System.out.println("position index: "+position.indexTest+" no: "+position.no);
            if(dic.containsKey(""+test.charAt(position.indexTest)))
            {
                ArrayList<String> strings=dic.get(""+test.charAt(position.indexTest)); 
                if(strings.size()>1&&position.no<strings.size()-1)
                     pos.push(new Position(position.indexTest,position.no+1));
                String str=strings.get(position.no);
                if(position.indexTest+str.length()==test.length())
                    return true;
                pos.push(new Position(position.indexTest+str.length(),0));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] st)
    {
        String[] dic={"world","hello","super","hell"};
        System.out.println("is 'hellworld' a combo: "+isCombo(dic,"superman"));
    } }
```

I have done similar problem. This solution gives true or false if given string is combination of dictionary words. It can be easily converted to get space-separated string. Its average complexity is O(n), where n: no of dictionary words in given string.